# Complains of a user that does not exist

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, exception, database-connection

I've specified the user of my application pool to be SERVER4\IUSR_SERVER4. And then I added this user to the SQL Server. But when I try to connect to the database I get the following error:

```
Server Error in '/BSHHD' Application.
Cannot open user default database. Login failed.
Login failed for user 'SERVER4\Administrator'.
```

What's driving me mad is there's no user named SERVER4\Administrator. What do I have to do in order to be able to properly connect to this SQL Server database from my website?

P.S. I think this is related with Membership authentication. Now I need to find out how Membership accesses SQL Server and where the login credentials are specified

Comment: I see 3 options. Run your site as a user - and use windows authentication, enforce NT authentication on site, login as user, or, finally, create a username + password specifically for your site to use.

Comment: The account running your app pool doesn't necessarily mean this is the credentials being used to connect to your database. How exactly are you connecting to the database?

Comment: Here's my connection string: Data Source=SERVER4\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=dok;Integrated Security=False;User ID=clerk;Password=dsmf1914   I simply create a SQL Connection and then open it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is, the app pool user is not necessarily the user you use to connect to MSSQL (as a guy in the comments already stated). After seeing your connection string, this is probably the case, and maybe, just maybe, the problem is not the user but it's default database.

I've had this error in the past: Try setting the user you use in the connection string (clerk's) default database to something else. This error is common when you've set a default database for a user before and now the database doesn't exist anymore or is having some problems.

You can change the user's default database using something like this:

```
Exec sp_defaultdb @loginame='clerk', @defdb='dok'
```

You can also use something like this but I've never used it:

```
ALTER LOGIN SQLLogin WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = AvailDBName
```

Also, there's no need to set the integrated security to false because it is the default value already. I hope this helps =)